# How to set Python apscheduler run job at 9,11,14,17,18 clock everyday

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am working on a period task with Python apscheduler, I want the code execute on 9:00, 11:00, 16:00, 17:00 every day and here is an example code for the job:

```
#coding=utf-8
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
from time import ctime

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=16)
def timed_job_one():
    print "16"
    print ctime()

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=17)
def timed_job_one():
    print "17"
    print ctime()

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=9)
def timed_job_two():
    print ctime()
    print '9'

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=11)
def timed_job_two():
    print ctime()
    print '11'

sched.start()
```

It works, but repeat four times code seems silly, so my problem is how to make the code short to set the function run at 9:00, 11:00, 16:00, 17:00 every day?

Comment: For future readers, the correct answer is the answer by Alex, the currently accepted one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why would you want to schedule the job four times separately when the documentation gives clear examples of how to do it properly?

```
@sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour='9,11,16,17')
def timed_job():
    print ctime()
```

See [this](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/triggers/cron.html#expression-types) and [this](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/triggers/cron.html#examples).

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
for h in [9,11,16,17]:
    @sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=h)
    def timed_job_one():
        print h
        print ctime()
```

or with multiple methods:

```
items = [(16,timed_job_one),(17,timed_job_one),(9,timed_job_two),(11,timed_job_two)]
for h,method in items:
 @sched.scheduled_job('cron', hour=h)
    def job():
        method(h)
```